# Frequency computation and fast fourier transform in Matlab

Tags: for-loop, fft

I have a question related to Fast Fourier transform. I want to calculate the phase and make FFT to draw power spectral density. However when I calculate the frequency `f`, there are some errors. This is my program code:

```
n = 1:32768;

T = 0.2*10^-9; % Sampling period

Fs = 1/T; % Sampling frequency

Fn = Fs/2; % Nyquist frequency

omega = 2*pi*200*10^6; % Carrier frequency

L = 32768; % % Length of signal

t = (0:L-1)*T; % Time vector

x_signal(n) = cos(omega*T*n + 0.1*randn(size(n))); % Additive phase noise (random)

y_signal(n) = sin(omega*T*n + 0.1*randn(size(n))); % Additive phase noise (random)

theta(n) = atan(y_signal(n)/x_signal(n));

f = (theta(n)-theta(n-1))/(2*pi)

Y = fft(f,t);

PSD = Y.*conj(Y); % Power Spectral Density

%Fv = linspace(0, 1, fix(L/2)+1)*Fn; % Frequency Vector
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted, you would get the error

> ```
> error: subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals
> ```

which refers to the operation `theta(n-1)` when `n=1` which results in an index of 0 (which is out of bounds since Matlab uses 1-based indexing). To avoid that could use a subset of indices in `n`:

```
f = (theta(n(2:end))-theta(n(1:end-1)))/(2*pi);
```

That said, if you are doing this to try to obtain an instantaneous measure of the frequency, then you will have a few more issues to deal with. The most trivial one is that you should also divide by `T`. Not as obvious is the fact that as given, `theta` is a scalar due to the use of the `/` operator (see [Matlab's `mrdivide`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html)) rather than the [`./` operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) which performs element-wise division. So a better expression would be:

```
theta(n) = atan(y_signal(n)./x_signal(n));
```

Now, the next problem you might notice is that you are actually losing some phase information since the result of `atan` is `[-pi/2,pi/2]` instead of the full `[-pi,pi]` range. To avoid this you should instead be using [`atan2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html):

```
theta(n) = atan2(y_signal(n), x_signal(n));
```

Even with this, you are likely to notice that the estimated frequency regularly has spikes whenever the phase jumps between near `-pi` and near `pi`. This can be avoided by computing the phase difference modulo `2*pi`:

```
f = mod(theta(n(2:end))-theta(n(1:end-1)),2*pi)/(2*pi*T);
```

A final thing to note: when calling the [`fft`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html), you should not be passing in a time variable (the input is implicitly assumed to be sampled at regular time intervals). You may however specify the desired length of the FFT. So, you would thus compute `Y` as follow:

```
Y = fft(f, L);
```

And you could then plot the resulting `PSD` using:

```
Fv = linspace(0, 1, fix(L/2)+1)*Fn; % Frequency Vector
plot(Fv, abs(PSD(1:L/2+1)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Honestly, this is quite difficult for me. I am just new to Matlab. I will try to understand your explanation. Btw, could you recommend some good books about Matlab?

Comment: When calculating the phase. I change to use
theta2(n2) = theta2(n2(1:end-1))+0.1*rand(size(n2)).
However, there is an error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Can you explain ?

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you got `n2` and `theta2` (the expression you just gave for `theta2` assumes it already exists), but from the given error message, it sounds like `n2` contains a value which is larger than the size of `theta2`. Also note that the indexing operation `n2(1:end-1)` excludes the last element of `n2`, thus the length of `n2(1:end-1)` is `length(n2)-1` which doesn't match `size(n2)` used as argument to `rand`.

Comment: As for recommended resource for Matlab, you could start with [some tutorials](https://www.mathworks.com/academia/student_center/tutorials/mltutorial_launchpad.html).

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Actually, I want to change the way to calculate theta in my program to be
theta(n) = theta(n(1:end-1))+0.1*rand(size(n)). 
theta and n is same with my previous program.

Comment: `theta(n(1:end-1))` would be problematic if you didn't first fix the problem with using `y_signal(n)/x_signal(n)` (you should really compute `theta` using `atan2`). Then I assume what you really want to do is add noise to the entire vector of values in `theta`. This can be done with the simpler expression `theta = theta + 0.1*rand(size(theta))`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: Dear SleuthEye. I also want to plot the average value of PSD with frequency domain (only a curve, not spectrum). I tried to used: plot(F, mean(PSD(1:L/2+1))). However it's not correct. Which command I have to use ? Thank you so much !